# CS Cart Skin - Inserting Javascripts in the <head> section

Tags: javascript, ftp, content-management-system, cs-cart

I'm trying to insert a javascript in a cs cart skin but nothing is happening after I inserted the code in scripts.tpl at common_templates. I've tried inserting it in {literal} {/literal} tags but still nothing is changing.please help.

------------------- This is my code right now in scripts.tpl: -------------------

```
{* $Id: scripts.tpl 10199 2010-07-26 09:11:31Z klerik $ *}

{script src="lib/jquery/jquery.js"}
{script src="js/core.js"}
{script src="js/ajax.js"}

{literal}<script type='text/javascript'>
var _vwo_code=(function(){
var account_id=45350,
settings_tolerance=2000,
library_tolerance=2500,
use_existing_jquery=false,
// DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
f=false,d=document;return{use_existing_jquery:function(){return use_existing_jquery;},library_tolerance:function(){return library_tolerance;},finish:function(){if(!f){f=true;var a=d.getElementById('_vis_opt_path_hides');if(a)a.parentNode.removeChild(a);}},finished:function(){return f;},load:function(a){var b=d.createElement('script');b.src=a;b.type='text/javascript';b.innerText;b.onerror=function(){_vwo_code.finish();};d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(b);},init:function(){settings_timer=setTimeout('_vwo_code.finish()',settings_tolerance);this.load('//dev.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/j.php?a='+account_id+'&u='+encodeURIComponent(d.URL)+'&r='+Math.random());var a=d.createElement('style'),b='body{opacity:0 !important;filter:alpha(opacity=0) !important;background:none !important;}',h=d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];a.setAttribute('id','_vis_opt_path_hides');a.setAttribute('type','text/css');if(a.styleSheet)a.styleSheet.cssText=b;else a.appendChild(d.createTextNode(b));h.appendChild(a);return settings_timer;}};}());_vwo_settings_timer=_vwo_code.init();
</script>{/literal}


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var index_script = '{$index_script|escape:"javascript"}';
var current_path = '{$config.current_path|escape:"javascript"}';
var changes_warning = '{$settings.Appearance.changes_warning|escape:"javascript"}';

var lang = {$ldelim}
    cannot_buy: '{$lang.cannot_buy|escape:"javascript"}',
    no_products_selected: '{$lang.no_products_selected|escape:"javascript"}',
    error_no_items_selected: '{$lang.error_no_items_selected|escape:"javascript"}',
    delete_confirmation: '{$lang.delete_confirmation|escape:"javascript"}',
    text_out_of_stock: '{$lang.text_out_of_stock|escape:javascript}',
    in_stock: '{$lang.in_stock|escape:javascript}',
    items: '{$lang.items|escape:javascript}',
    text_required_group_product: '{$lang.text_required_group_product|escape:javascript}',
    notice: '{$lang.notice|escape:"javascript"}',
    warning: '{$lang.warning|escape:"javascript"}',
    loading: '{$lang.loading|escape:"javascript"}',
    none: '{$lang.none|escape:"javascript"}',
    text_are_you_sure_to_proceed: '{$lang.text_are_you_sure_to_proceed|escape:"javascript"}',
    text_invalid_url: '{$lang.text_invalid_url|escape:"javascript"}',
    text_cart_changed: '{$lang.text_cart_changed|escape:"javascript"}',
    error_validator_email: '{$lang.error_validator_email|escape:"javascript"}',
    error_validator_confirm_email: '{$lang.error_validator_confirm_email|escape:"javascript"}',
    error_validator_phone: '{$lang.error_validator_phone|escape:"javascript"}',
    error_validator_integer: '{$lang.error_validator_integer|escape:"javascript"}',
    error_validator_multiple: '{$lang.error_validator_multiple|escape:"javascript"}',
    error_validator_password: '{$lang.error_validator_password|escape:"javascript"}',
    error_validator_required: '{$lang.error_validator_required|escape:"javascript"}',
    error_validator_zipcode: '{$lang.error_validator_zipcode|escape:"javascript"}',
    error_validator_message: '{$lang.error_validator_message|escape:"javascript"}',
    text_page_loading: '{$lang.text_page_loading|escape:"javascript"}',
    view_cart: '{$lang.view_cart|escape:javascript}',
    checkout: '{$lang.checkout|escape:javascript}',
    product_added_to_cart: '{$lang.product_added_to_cart|escape:javascript}',
    products_added_to_cart: '{$lang.products_added_to_cart|escape:javascript}',
    product_added_to_wl: '{$lang.product_added_to_wl|escape:javascript}',
    product_added_to_cl: '{$lang.product_added_to_cl|escape:javascript}',
    close: '{$lang.close|escape:javascript}',
    error: '{$lang.error|escape:"javascript"}',
    error_ajax: '{$lang.error_ajax|escape:"javascript"}',
    text_changes_not_saved: '{$lang.text_changes_not_saved|escape:"javascript"}',
    text_data_changed: '{$lang.text_data_changed|escape:"javascript"}'
{$rdelim}

var warning_mark = "&lt;&lt;";

var currencies = {$ldelim}
    'primary': {$ldelim}
        'decimals_separator': '{$currencies.$primary_currency.decimals_separator|escape:javascript}',
        'thousands_separator': '{$currencies.$primary_currency.thousands_separator|escape:javascript}',
        'decimals': '{$currencies.$primary_currency.decimals|escape:javascript}',
        'coefficient': '{$currencies.$primary_currency.coefficient|escape:javascript}'
    {$rdelim},
    'secondary': {$ldelim}
        'decimals_separator': '{$currencies.$secondary_currency.decimals_separator|escape:javascript}',
        'thousands_separator': '{$currencies.$secondary_currency.thousands_separator|escape:javascript}',
        'decimals': '{$currencies.$secondary_currency.decimals|escape:javascript}',
        'coefficient': '{$currencies.$secondary_currency.coefficient}'
    {$rdelim}
{$rdelim};

var cart_language = '{$smarty.const.CART_LANGUAGE}';
var images_dir = '{$images_dir}';
var notice_displaying_time = {if $settings.Appearance.notice_displaying_time}{$settings.Appearance.notice_displaying_time}{else}0{/if};
var cart_prices_w_taxes = {if ($settings.Appearance.cart_prices_w_taxes == 'Y' && 'CHECKOUT'|defined) || ($settings.Appearance.show_prices_taxed_clean == 'Y' && !'CHECKOUT'|defined)}true{else}false{/if};
var translate_mode = {if "TRANSLATION_MODE"|defined}true{else}false{/if};
var iframe_urls = new Array();
var iframe_extra = new Array();
var regexp = new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){$ldelim}
    jQuery.runCart('C');
{$rdelim});

document.write('<style>.cm-noscript {$ldelim} display:none {$rdelim}</style>'); // hide noscript tags
//]]>
</script>
{literal}
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.dropdown li').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
        $('> .dir',this).addClass('open');
        $('ul:first',this).css('display', 'block');
    },function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
        $('.open',this).removeClass('open');
        $('ul:first',this).css('display', 'none');
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
{/literal}
{hook name="index:scripts"}
{/hook}
```

------------------- The part of the code that wont insert: -------------------

```
{literal}<script type='text/javascript'>
    var _vwo_code=(function(){
    var account_id=45350,
    settings_tolerance=2000,
    library_tolerance=2500,
    use_existing_jquery=false,
    // DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
    f=false,d=document;return{use_existing_jquery:function(){return use_existing_jquery;},library_tolerance:function(){return library_tolerance;},finish:function(){if(!f){f=true;var a=d.getElementById('_vis_opt_path_hides');if(a)a.parentNode.removeChild(a);}},finished:function(){return f;},load:function(a){var b=d.createElement('script');b.src=a;b.type='text/javascript';b.innerText;b.onerror=function(){_vwo_code.finish();};d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(b);},init:function(){settings_timer=setTimeout('_vwo_code.finish()',settings_tolerance);this.load('//dev.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/j.php?a='+account_id+'&u='+encodeURIComponent(d.URL)+'&r='+Math.random());var a=d.createElement('style'),b='body{opacity:0 !important;filter:alpha(opacity=0) !important;background:none !important;}',h=d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];a.setAttribute('id','_vis_opt_path_hides');a.setAttribute('type','text/css');if(a.styleSheet)a.styleSheet.cssText=b;else a.appendChild(d.createTextNode(b));h.appendChild(a);return settings_timer;}};}());_vwo_settings_timer=_vwo_code.init();
    </script>{/literal}
```

Comment: please share the code of scripts.tpl

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly cs cart caches
but from my experience on prestashop, i need to clear my cache whenever i add some script to tpl as it uses smarty cache.
please try clearing cache.
or in worst case put your javascript in external file and add
{script src="js/custom.js"}

Comment: and also if _vwo_settings_timer=_vwo_code.init();is using jquery ?
then its better to put $( document ).ready(function() {
  _vwo_settings_timer=_vwo_code.init();
});

Comment: Sorry to full you with so many comments. but one way of testing it is either cache problem or not is change some value {script src="lib/jquery/jquery.js"} to {script src="lib/jquery/jquery1.js"} and see if thats reflecting in chrome dev tools.

Comment: I already tried creating a new js and include the source in the scripts.tpl but still nothing. I tried deleting everything inside the scripts.tpl just to check if its actually responding to my changes and to my surprise, code is still there. Its bazaar cuz the styles.tpl and scripts.tpl are in the same directory and I was able to do some changes to the styles so meaning I'm touching right files.

Comment: Nope its not using jquery. I have done this with other sites. Its kinda of my first time to use this cs cart / smarty template.

Comment: when u delete everything inside the scripts.tpl it still working?

Comment: Its alright, keep the comments coming. I've been searching for days for this :|

Comment: try this "
 append &cc at the end of the url, so for example it would be:
admin.php?dispatch=categories.manage&cc "

Comment: can you share your url ? please add &cc at the end and try

Comment: yeah :| everything. This is the site that Im working on right now. http://www.giftbasketsdirect.com.au/

Comment: Hey Venkat, I cleared the cache of the site, and for some reason the site broke down. Everything was blank. I think there's some sort of bug in this cs cart. I had to change skins and reapply the changes I made in css.

Comment: could you able to fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my_changes add-on and hook to scripts
I see you are using v3

- to file

  ```
  PRO: skins/[SKIN_NAME]/customer/addons/my_changes/hooks/index/scripts.post.tpl
  ULT: stores/[STORE_ID]/skins/[SKIN_NAME]/customer/addons/my_changes/hooks/index/scripts.post.tpl
  ```
- add content

  ```
  {literal}<script type='text/javascript'>
  var _vwo_code=(function(){
  var account_id=45350,
  settings_tolerance=2000,
  library_tolerance=2500,
  use_existing_jquery=false,
  // DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
  f=false,d=document;return{use_existing_jquery:function(){return use_existing_jquery;},library_tolerance:function(){return library_tolerance;},finish:function(){if(!f){f=true;var a=d.getElementById('_vis_opt_path_hides');if(a)a.parentNode.removeChild(a);}},finished:function(){return f;},load:function(a){var b=d.createElement('script');b.src=a;b.type='text/javascript';b.innerText;b.onerror=function(){_vwo_code.finish();};d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(b);},init:function(){settings_timer=setTimeout('_vwo_code.finish()',settings_tolerance);this.load('//dev.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/j.php?a='+account_id+'&u='+encodeURIComponent(d.URL)+'&r='+Math.random());var a=d.createElement('style'),b='body{opacity:0 !important;filter:alpha(opacity=0) !important;background:none !important;}',h=d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];a.setAttribute('id','_vis_opt_path_hides');a.setAttribute('type','text/css');if(a.styleSheet)a.styleSheet.cssText=b;else a.appendChild(d.createTextNode(b));h.appendChild(a);return settings_timer;}};}());_vwo_settings_timer=_vwo_code.init();
  </script>{/literal}
  ```
- Clear cache (very important)  http://www.example.com/admin.php?cc

Now should be listed into the header

Please also check if you have any hooks that override scripts ;)